# How do I automatically generate controller index pages showing links to all of the other methods In ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to automatically generate HTML output from controller Index pages that lists all the RESTful web methods inside that particular controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [swagger](http://swagger.io/). This generates a specification of your API, that is simple and readable.

For generating the swagger.json and presenting the UI you should use a NuGet package like [SwashBuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)